# GCS boto authentication on RPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, boto, sudo

I have this simple script that spits out the buckets in my GCS:

```
import boto
import gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin
import os
import shutil
import StringIO
import tempfile
import time

# URI scheme for Cloud Storage.
GOOGLE_STORAGE = 'gs'
# URI scheme for accessing local files.
LOCAL_FILE = 'file'

header_values = {"x-goog-project-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"}

uri = boto.storage_uri('', GOOGLE_STORAGE)
for bucket in uri.get_all_buckets(headers=header_values):
  print bucket.name
```

The top of my `~/.boto` file has the following (with real values for everything inside brackets):

```
# Google OAuth2 service account credentials (for "gs://" URIs):
gs_service_key_file = /home/pi/dev/camera/cl-camera-<id>.json
gs_service_client_id = '<user>@<id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
```

Everything works fine when running *without* sudo, but once I add sudo (I need access to GPIO pins since this is on a RPi), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gcs-test.py", line 24, in <module>
    for bucket in uri.get_all_buckets(headers=header_values):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/storage_uri.py", line 584, in get_all_buckets
    conn = self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/storage_uri.py", line 140, in connect
    **connection_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/gs/connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    suppress_consec_slashes=suppress_consec_slashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 191, in __init__
    validate_certs=validate_certs, profile_name=profile_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 569, in __init__
    host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/auth.py", line 1021, in get_auth_handler
    'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 3 handlers were checked. ['OAuth2Auth', 'OAuth2ServiceAccountAuth', 'HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials
```

Any ideas as to what's happening and why it's only when I run it with sudo?

Comment: Sudo changes your _**permissions**_. Check the permission of `~/.boto` and files into this directory.

Comment: @stovfl I gave the ~./boto full system permissions: ```-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17293 May 12 17:59 /home/pi/.boto``` but it still shows the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I figure this one out.  Since I'm running it as root now, it looks for the .boto file in a different place (`/root/.boto` instead of `/home/pi/.boto`), so I did the following to create a new config file and it worked:

```
$ sudo su
$ gsutil config -e
```